# C#- Bluetooth programming resources

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

I've been looking around the web for ways to program a C# application that does general Bluetooth functionality. I'm trying to connect a BlueSMIRF so that a file can be transferred through a Windows desktop application. However, this seems to be one area where there aren't any real libraries or tutorials... most of the materials for Windows seem to be in C++. Am I missing something here or does Visual C# not include support for Bluetooth in its class libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library which is written in C# and supports Bluetooth-Communication: [32feet](http://32feet.codeplex.com/)

I hope I could help!